# HAProxy not load balancing S3 multipart uploads from mc (MinIO client)

Tags: amazon-s3, haproxy, minio

Here's what I'm trying to do: I have a bunch of hosts running reverse proxied MinIO instances (using nginx) and I want to load balance requests by using HAProxy. I don't want to use TLS termination and instead terminate at the targeted hosts.

I used [Sidekick](https://github.com/minio/sidekick) earlier, but that doesn't support TLS passthrough. The behavior there is however as I would expect: different S3 multipart requests are sent to different hosts.

I've setup HAProxy to load balance between my 12 hosts and ran some tests using `balance roundrobin` and `balance leastconn`, but whatever I do my multipart uploads all end up being sent to a **single host**. Weirdly enough when I use `mc ls` to list all objects in my S3 backend I can see the requests being routed and logged on the host running haproxy. If I use `mc cp` however, **nothing gets logged** -- even when the upload finishes. Activating request tracing in my MinIO instances shows me that all chunks end up being sent to the same host. I would have expected them to be distributed amongst all 12 hosts. AFAIK there is no keep-alive in mc and every chunk request is independent from the last.

It looks like this might be related to the `mc` commands I send, but I've found some commands (`du`, `rm`) which will generate multiple log entries on the haproxy server indicating that different requests for the same command were routed to different servers.

My haproxy is version 2.0.14 and I'm using the following haproxy.cfg:

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug
  maxconn 32768
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon

defaults
  log     global
  mode    tcp
  option  tcplog
  timeout connect     5s
  timeout client     50s
  timeout server    450s

frontend https
  bind :443
  default_backend bk_app

backend bk_app
  balance roundrobin
  option httpchk GET /minio/health/live
  option ssl-hello-chk
  http-check expect status 200
  server fs-testcluster-robert2-n1 10.10.11.150:443 check-ssl verify none
  server fs-testcluster-robert2-n4 10.10.11.151:443 check-ssl verify none
  server fs-testcluster-robert2-n2 10.10.11.152:443 check-ssl verify none
  server fs-testcluster-robert2-n5 10.10.11.153:443 check-ssl verify none
  server fs-testcluster-robert2-n3 10.10.11.154:443 check-ssl verify none
  server fs-testcluster-robert2-n6 10.10.11.155:443 check-ssl verify none
  server fs-testcluster-robert-n1 10.10.12.196:443 check-ssl verify none
  server fs-testcluster-robert-n2 10.10.12.198:443 check-ssl verify none
  server fs-testcluster-robert-n3 10.10.12.237:443 check-ssl verify none
  server fs-testcluster-robert-n4 10.10.11.160:443 check-ssl verify none
  server fs-testcluster-robert-n5 10.10.11.161:443 check-ssl verify none
  server fs-testcluster-robert-n6 10.10.11.162:443 check-ssl verify none
```

Can anybody explain what's going on or what I might have misconfigured?

Comment: I'll try to have a look at the `mc` code in the next few days to rule out any keep-alive there. I would expect this to affect load balancing with Sidekick in the same way, though. That's why I initially ruled it out.